# Wireless Socket file transfer c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, asyncsocket

I've a code that send messages between server and client via 'WLAN', I am trying to send files between server and client (large files) wireless.Tried some codes

this code send messages

```
  ` string msg = richTextTxMessage.Text;
    NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(m_clientSocket);
    System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
    streamWriter.WriteLine(msg);streamWriter.Flush();
            ` 

       this code am trying to send files 
            byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString ());
            if(m_clientSocket != null){
                m_clientSocket.Send (byData);
            }`
```

Comment: @TonyHopkinson how to send files? my code is not working

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Naren my code is now working . How to send large file via socket wireless. i tried of bunch of codes from intrnet they connecting wlan computers but now wireless android devices

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your LAN/WLAN and WiFi networks have the same level of permissions/connectivity. Often, administrators reduce access rights for WiFi networks (as they're less secure). For example, it may be necessary to setup extra VPN connection before you can access something in your LAN. So

1. Contact your system administrators about the differences and gotchas
2. Grab the traffic with help of WireShark or similar sniffer and compare both cases (LAN/WLAN and WiFi)

Comment: You know i can receive messages between LAN/WLAN  computers and wireless devices but i cant send files between wireless devices

Comment: @GeorgeJeffin Please be more specific.Tell us the exact error you got.

Comment: @Naren i  tried some codes from internet that not transfer file wireless so how to do that? big files

Comment: @George Jeffin It may also be caused by mobile device restriction. For example, Windows Phone 7 can't act like a server (if I remember correctly, has no API to listen for incoming connects). So try to implement some interim approach once two devices go to dedicated server as clients and then exchange the files through the server.

Comment: @YurySchkatula what about android ?

Answer (score 0):

read your file into a byte array and send it for example:
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("file");
m_clientSocket.Send (data);

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("Reallybigfile.avi");
socket.Send(data);
```

socket will have to be created, your gonna have to google that yourself

Comment: Can you show me a example ? I am new in byte[] things like that thanks

Comment: & what will be the file receive code (large file) ?

Comment: something like byte[] data = socket.receive();